# Large Hot Network Questions icon is the old one

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The "icon-48.png" that's used on the full Hot Network Questions page still has the old design. I tried clearing my cache.

I am on latest chrome, 50.0.2661.102 m.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be fixed now, both on HNQ and on the network profile (where it was also showing as the beta logo until today).  You might need to force your browser to refresh the page.  (For me, one browser updated automatically but another had to be forced.)